# Error NextJS 13.4.2 using NextAuth and MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, next.js, next-auth

How can I resolve the "The top-level-await experiment is not enabled" error that occurs when adding MongoDB in the `[...nextauth]` file of my open-source project, Electronic Patient Records? Here are the relevant links:

Project URL: https://epr-erwinagpasa.vercel.app

GitHub Repository: https://github.com/erwinagpasa/epr

[image]

Comment: Have you tried putting the "topLevelAwait: true" after line 4 of the next.config.js file?

Answer (score 1):

What did the trick on my codebase is including in the **next.config.js**

```
    /** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
    const nextConfig = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
    experimental: { appDir: true },
    webpack(config) {
        config.experiments = { ...config.experiments, topLevelAwait: true }
        return config
    },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```